# Custom cropped Wordpress thumbnails, overwritten when using crop in the media library

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails, crop

I defined custom thumbnail sizes in my functions.php file using this function:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
add_image_size( 'address', 960, 250, true );
}
```

Which works fine as long as I don't use the 'Edit Image' function (crop tool) in the Wordpress back-end, after uploading my image. When I do so, the height that I defined (250px) is not considered anymore.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known problem. I've read somewhere that it will be solved in one of the upcoming releases. Until then you can use the following code in your `functions.php`. Just adjust the image sizes.

```
if (function_exists('add_image_size')) {
    add_image_size( 'dummy-1', 940, 450, true );
    add_image_size( 'dummy-2', 480, 0 );
}

global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $name =&gt; $image_size ){
    update_option( $name."_size_w", $image_size['width'] );
    update_option( $name."_size_h", $image_size['height'] );
    update_option( $name."_crop", $image_size['crop'] );
}

add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'regenerate_custom_image_sizes' );
function regenerate_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ){
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $name =&gt; $size ){
        $sizes[] = $name;
    }
    return $sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  'Edit Image' function is considering only the original file ('full') image for cropping , resize, rotate and other minor "editing" . you have an option there to specify if you want it for all sizes, only thumbnails, or all sizes except thumbnails..

Comment: But my goal is to crop something out of the picture, which I don't want to show in any of them. Yet ultimately, if I defined a precise thumbnail size for balance purpose, it's for not breaking the layout. I don't get why it considers the hard edit crop and not my function/layout setting.
My function.php setting is supposed to crop the image in the first place (true).